# javascript validation if a radio selected then make a dropdown required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio field in my form that has 3 elements. color, sleeve, size

based on the radio selection I do a show/hide of 3 select boxes.
    select- color-type red, blue, green etc, etc
    select - sleeve-type full sleeve, half sleeve, sleeveless
    select - size-type small, medium, large, extra large
how can I make the select field mandatory if one of the related radio is selected
example: if color radio is selected then drop-down color-type is a required field, else if, radio sleeve is selected then drop-down sleeve-type is selected and so on.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function showLayer(layerName)
  {
    document.getElementById(layerName).style.display="block";
  }
  function hideLayer(layerName)
  {

  document.getElementById(layerName).style.display="none";
  }
</script>

<form method="post" action="" name="rregister" id="rregister">

    <div>
      <label><input type="radio"  name="ctype" id="color" value="color" onclick="showLayer('hlayer1'); hideLayer('hlayer2'); hideLayer('hlayer3');" required>Color</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="ctype" id="sleeve" value="sleeve" onclick="showLayer('hlayer2'); hideLayer('hlayer1'); hideLayer('hlayer3');">Sleeve</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="ctype" id="size" value="size" onclick="showLayer('hlayer3'); hideLayer('hlayer2'); hideLayer('hlayer1');">Size</label>
    </div>

    <div id="hlayer1" style="display: none;">
      <select id="colortype" name="colortype">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Color</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="hlayer2" style="display: none;">
      <select id="sleevetype" name="sleevetype">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Sleeve </option>
        <option value="Half">Half</option>
        <option value="Full">Full</option>
        <option value="Sleeveless">Sleeveless</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="hlayer3" style="display: none;">
      <select id="sizetype" name="sizetype">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Size</option>
        <option value="S">Small</option>
        <option value="M">Medium</option>
        <option value="L">Large</option>
        <option value="XL">Xtra Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: please add your code

Comment: I've added the form code, @daddygames

Comment: Please see the code @Andrew Daly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. You can get the immediate child of the div you are setting the `style.display` attribute and set that child as required. At the moment the first child is your `select` input, keep in mind this may cause trouble in the future if you decide to add more elements.

If you want a more robust way to go around I would add another parameter to your `showLayer()` and `hideLayer()` functions representing the ID of the select field you want to make required and get these elements directly.

Working Example:

```js
function showLayer(layerName, myField)
  {
    document.getElementById(layerName).style.display="block";
    
    //set the appropriate field as required
    document.getElementById(myField).required = true;
  }
  function hideLayer(layerName, myField)
  {

  document.getElementById(layerName).style.display="none";
  //set fields as not required
  document.getElementById(myField).required = false;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" name="rregister" id="rregister">

    <div>
      <label><input type="radio"  name="ctype" id="color" value="color" onclick="showLayer('hlayer1', 'colortype'); hideLayer('hlayer2', 'sleevetype'); hideLayer('hlayer3', 'sizetype');">Color</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="ctype" id="sleeve" value="sleeve" onclick="showLayer('hlayer2', 'sleevetype'); hideLayer('hlayer1', 'colortype'); hideLayer('hlayer3', 'sizetype');">Sleeve</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="ctype" id="size" value="size" onclick="showLayer('hlayer3', 'sizetype'); hideLayer('hlayer2', 'sleevetype'); hideLayer('hlayer1', 'colortype');">Size</label>
    </div>

    <div id="hlayer1" style="display: none;">
      <select id="colortype" name="colortype">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Color</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="hlayer2" style="display: none;">
      <select id="sleevetype" name="sleevetype">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Sleeve </option>
        <option value="Half">Half</option>
        <option value="Full">Full</option>
        <option value="Sleeveless">Sleeveless</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="hlayer3" style="display: none;">
      <select id="sizetype" name="sizetype">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Size</option>
        <option value="S">Small</option>
        <option value="M">Medium</option>
        <option value="L">Large</option>
        <option value="XL">Xtra Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice that I added the appropriate input ID as arguments in your HTML